# ASP.NET - How to track event from previous postback?

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have a requirement to check for a certain condition on postback before redirecting (Response.Redirect) to another page.

Note... I cannot use JavaScript to detect whether or not to confirm (this is also a requirement) :s

Pseudo:

```
protected void lbtnRedirect_OnClick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (showConfirm)
    {
       // Set flag for client side
       this.ShowConfirm = true;

       // Track this event for next postback.
    }
    else
    {
       Response.Redirect("somepage.aspx");
    }
}
```

If the showConfrim flag == true, then the client will be show a modal dialog box asking them if they are sure they want to redirect.  If the user clicks on "Yes", then the page posts back and the desired effect is that the lbtnRedirect_OnClick event is fired.  How would I about tracking the lbtnRedirect event?

Edit:
I have no problem tracking the flag to show the modal (yes JS must be used to show the modal... somethings you just cannot get rid of :)). I should have been more clear.

It is when the user clicks "Yes" to continue the redirect.  The page will postback again but needs to know which event to go through.

i.e. Suppose there are 3 onclick events, 1) lbtnRedirect1_Onclick 2) lbtnRedirect2_OnClick 3) lbtnRedirect3_OnClick... each of which does the confirm check.

Each onclick event does the check. So when the user clicks on "Yes" on the modal, how does the page know which event to drop back into?

Comment: modal pop ups is pretty much a javascript thing. if you have devexpress they have a pop up control you could try.

Comment: Are you allowed to use javascript at all? I would use javascript to show the modal dialog and make the dialog's 'Yes' button initiate the redirect.

Answer (score 2):

You can use ViewState if you're in WebForms.

Implement a ShowConfirm property encapsulating ViewState["ShowConfirm"].

In the first postback you'll set ShowConfirm 'true', and this will activate that modal during the render (if ShowConfirm is true, that's setting as visible 'true' some control).

In the next postback, you'll set ShowConfirm 'false' because is 'true', and finally you'll do the whole redirect!

Comment: This is the correct answer. The code sample from the OP is basically the exact logic to implement it after following the ViewState backed Property there would just be some panel showing/hiding in the first iteration before the redirection.

Answer (score 0):

You can use an ajax call from javascript to set the required values.

Answer (score 0):

Since the postback will happen before even the execution reaches to your button click event we need a workaround here, And if you don't need JS as your requirement, so take a look at

[Implementing Client Callbacks Programmatically without Postbacks in ASP.NET](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178208.aspx)

This is much like a wrapper for XMLHttp Ajax call IMHO.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot easily create a model form, without javascipt.

One suggestion I would make is to have panels in your page.

Panel one is visible.

On submit one; panel one hides and panel two is visible asking for a confirmation.

On panel two is a confirm button, clicking this button your redirection is performed.